# What is Docker URL

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I am building a gradle project in Jenkins. and client has asked to build the project in docker image. i am new to Jenkins and docker(i am able to build the project normally on Jenkins) i have installed the docker plugin and now it asks for **DOCKER URL** and **Docker API** under cloud settings.  what are those and how to configure the docker. i am running Jenkins on the remote server, which is setup by another person. i don't have access to shell command, i have to use docker and build the project, and what is **dockerfile** and how to build and what to put in it.

Comment: Is the point to compile and assemble the code while running in a Docker container, or is the point to build a Docker image containing your project?

Comment: compile and assemble the code in Docker container and and make build of project in it @DavidM.Karr

Answer (score 0):

As per the jenkins docker plugin page 
The URL to use to access your Docker server API (e.g: http://172.16.42.43:4243)
But I will recommend you to use https://your_local_docker_machine_ip_here:2376

Comment: my docker is installed on remote server. and now i dont know what to do after that and when i put he URL in DOCKER URL is says "Unsupported protocol scheme found: 'http://MY_REMOTE_IP:44633/'. Only 'tcp://' or 'unix://' supported.

Comment: any solutions on this? Im stuck at the same problem